# Issues With Reading Input

Tags: python-3.x

```
 while True:
   d=input()
   data=d.split(":",2)
   if d.strip()=='':
       break
```

This is code I am using to read data from keyboard.suppose the input is:

```
Williams:Muguruza:3-6,6-3,6-3
```

my expected output is `['Williams','Murguza','3-6,6-3,6-3']`.But the output I am getting is `''`(when I use `print(d)`).Why am I getting this.Here I am using while loop because user supplies continuous input and input is terminated by blank line

Edit:Sorry for the incomplete information.The input will be like this:

```
Djokovic:Murray:7-6,4-6,7-6,2-6,6-2
Murray:Djokovic:7-5,7-5
Williams:Muguruza:3-6,6-3,6-3
```

I have to read all the input and finally when user provides blank line(pressing ENTER key two times) it is the end of input.For each input I have to extract some information like `data` and some other stuff.I am giving the complete code:

```
  while True:
    d=input()
    if d.strip()=='':
        break
    data=d.split(":",2)
    try:
        b=isinstance(playerstats,dict)
    except NameError:
        playerstats={}
    if data[0] not in playerstats:
        playerstats[data[0]]={}
        playerstats[data[0]]["5setswon"]=0
        playerstats[data[0]]["3setswon"]=0
        playerstats[data[0]]["setswon"]=0
        playerstats[data[0]]["gameswon"]=0
        playerstats[data[0]]["setslost"]=0
        playerstats[data[0]]["gameslost"]=0
        playerstats[data[0]]

    if data[1] not in playerstats:
        playerstats[data[1]]={}
        playerstats[data[1]]["5setswon"]=0
        playerstats[data[1]]["3setswon"]=0
        playerstats[data[1]]["setswon"]=0
        playerstats[data[1]]["gameswon"]=0
        playerstats[data[1]]["setslost"]=0
        playerstats[data[1]]["gameslost"]=0

    if data[2].count("-")>3:
        playerstats[data[0]]["5setswon"]+=1
    else:
        playerstats[data[0]]["3setswon"]+=1
    p1=data[2][::4]
    p2=data[2][2::4]
    setswon=sum(x>y for x,y in zip(p1,p2))
    setslost=data[2].count("-")-setswon
    playerstats[data[0]]["setswon"]+=setswon
    playerstats[data[0]]["setslost"]+=setslost
    playerstats[data[1]]["setswon"]+=setslost
    playerstats[data[1]]["setslost"]+=setswon
    gameswon=sum(int(x) for x in p1)
    playerstats[data[0]]["gameswon"]+=gameswon

    playerstats[data[1]]["gameslost"]+=gameswon
    gameslost=sum(int(x) for x in p2)
    playerstats[data[0]]["gameslost"]+=gameslost
    playerstats[data[1]]["gameswon"]+=gameslost
```

The main theme of my code is to maintain a dictionary for each player with some info like games lost etc..But I am getting error like this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#2>", line 29, in <module>
 if data[2].count("-")>3:
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I expect the code I used to read input from user is wrong.But I really do not  know where I am going wrong.The final output what i should get is:

```
{'Williams': {'5setswon': 0, '3setswon': 1, 'setswon': 2, 'gameswon': 0, 'setslost': 0, 'gameslost': 0}, 'Muguruza': {'5setswon': 0, '3setswon': 0, 'setswon': 0, 'gameswon': 0, 'setslost': 0, 'gameslost': 0}}
```

the above is just a sample output

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not clearly indicate where you trying to `print(d)` in your loop. The following example seems to accomplish what you are asking for. It demonstrates an interactive session with the interpreter.

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> while True:
    text = input().strip()
    if not text:
        break
    data = text.split(':', 2)
    print(data)


Williams:Muguruza:3-6,6-3,6-3
['Williams', 'Muguruza', '3-6,6-3,6-3']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 2, in <module>
    text = input().strip()
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```